# Are there Ansi escape sequences for superscript and subscript?

Tags: ansi-escape

I'm playing around with ANSI escape sequences, e.g.

```bash
echo -e "\e[91mHello\e[m"
```

on a Linux console to display colored text.

Now I try to use superscript and subscript output like `a=b²`.

I read [here](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) about: `Partial Line Down (subscript)` and `Partial Line Up (superscript)` but I'm not sure about the exact syntax and even which terminal client might supports this.

Any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly some *commercial* product supports it, but it's not supported by any terminal emulator you'll encounter (unless someone modifies one just to prove a point).

The standard describes *possible* escape sequences, but there is no *requirement* that any given sequence is supported by any terminal.  There are commonly supported (and assumed) sequences such as clearing the screen, but even for that, not all terminals have supported the feature.

The reason is that terminal emulators are generally used with applications (such as text editors) which assume a regular set of rows/columns, and that the text is shown compactly (no extra space such as would be needed to allow for *partial line* movement.  Back in the day when people used typewriters, it was common to have 1.5 or 2.0 line-spacing, and get no more than 33 lines on a page. That changed, long ago.

The need for subscripts/superscripts didn't go away — Unicode provides a usable set of characters with that representation (see [**Superscripts and Subscripts**
*Range: 2070–209F*](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf))

Further reading:

- [*Your New **Royal** Portable*](https://typewriters.ch/files/manuals/royal_portable_manual.pdf) (1953).
- [*Line Spacing - **Butterick's Practical Typography***](http://practicaltypography.com/line-spacing.html)
- [**`console_codes`** - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)