# ANSI escape sequence for collapsing/folding text (maybe hierarchically)

Tags: linux, terminal, ansi-escape, terminal-emulator

E.g. in [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/), by printing `travis_fold:start:<section-name>` and `travis_fold:end:<section-name>`, which behave like escape codes for Travis, it will fold the text away.
See [here about Travis folding](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1065).
See for example [this output](https://travis-ci.org/rwth-i6/returnn/jobs/440836923).

The same would be very useful in general for Linux/Unix terminals.
Are there any [ANSI escape sequences/codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) extensions which do something like this (and of course corresponding terminal emulators which handle those)?

---

Existing escape code (and extensions):

- ANSI colors: [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences)
- [iTerm2 list, with some extended escape codes](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html)
- [hterm list](https://github.com/chromium/hterm/blob/master/doc/ControlSequences.md)
- [other extensions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes)
- [collected list](https://github.com/albertz/wiki/blob/master/terminal-escape-codes.md)
- superscript/subscript: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473819/are-there-ansi-escape-sequences-for-superscript-and-subscript)
- hyperlink support: [overview in various emulators](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda)
- images: [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/614), [sixel](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel)
- current directory information: [iTerm2](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3939)
- generic HTML: [DomTerm](https://domterm.org/) ([article](https://opensource.com/article/18/1/introduction-domterm-terminal-emulator), [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/670062/)), [GraphTerm](https://github.com/mitotic/graphterm), [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some list:

- [DomTerm](https://domterm.org/): supports it ([details](https://github.com/PerBothner/DomTerm/issues/54))
- [Hyper](https://hyper.is): [feature request](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1093)
- [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/): [feature request](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/1875)
- [Final Term](https://github.com/p-e-w/finalterm): supports it ([article](http://linuxbsdos.com/2013/08/07/final-term-a-terminal-emulator-to-rule-them-all/)) but is no longer maintained